# how to add more consumer in same processor in apache nifi ConsumeKafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Kafka topic has around 100 partitions, I am using Apache nifi ConsumeKafka read the data from that kafka and send some other server.

Currently this nifi consumeKafka processor has only one consumer, I want to have similar number of consumer to match with partitions, I did not any option to increases the number of consumer, Currently I am adding new processor to same consumer group, I though this approach right one.

How to increase consumers in same nifi consumerKafka processor ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? "it is possible to increase the number of concurrent tasks on the processor under the Scheduling tab when configuring. This allows more processes to execute simultaneously, providing greater throughput" - https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running a standalone nifi instance a single consumer thread will start. To increase the number of threads, you need to increase the "Concurrent Tasks" on the processor and it will start those many thread.

In your case as the topic has 100 partitions, to have the best optimal performance you should be having total 100 threads on your consumer.

[You can find the property on this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLn24.png)